# How to animate 3D data in python using Mayavi

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, data-visualization, mayavi.mlab

I have many 3D arrays containing data of a quantity at every point in space. Therefore,

```
A10[4][3][6]
```

gives the value of this quantity at coordinates (4,3,6). This array `A10` contains the values at some time `t = 10`. There are arrays like this for 200 units of time. The value of this quantity changes with time in space. I wish to animate this data.

How can I do this using Mayavi or any other software?

Comment: What have you tried thusfar? Implement answer in your question (prevents down-voting because it shows effort). See my questions and suggestions in my answer.  (End of Review).

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) [animation.FuncAnimation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation) to make 3D animation with [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/).

You will find [a 3D animation working example](https://matplotlib.org//3.1.1/gallery/animation/random_walk.html) in the official documentation.

---

You may also keep [mayavi](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi) as 3D render, in that case you may take a look on [mlab_animating](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab_animating.html)  on the [mayavi](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi) official documentation

---

Note also that your question is near similar to:

- [animating-a-mayavi-points3d-plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287185/animating-a-mayavi-points3d-plot)
- [animating-with-mayavi-mlab-points3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51965111/animating-with-mayavi-mlab-points3d?rq=1)